# Drawing pictureBox c#

Tags: c#, picturebox, graphicspath

i'm trying to make a customized picturebox that looks like this -

[image]

So far, all i've made is - 
[image]

using this code -

```
    protected void UpdateRegion()
    {
        var path = new GraphicsPath();
        Point[] points =
        {
            new Point( 0, 0),
            new Point(0, ClientSize.Height-80),
            new Point(80 , ClientSize.Height),
            new Point(ClientSize.Width-80, ClientSize.Height),
            new Point(ClientSize.Width,  ClientSize.Height-80),
            new Point(ClientSize.Width , 0)
        };
        path.AddPolygon(points);
        path.FillMode = FillMode.Winding;
        this.Region = new Region(path);
    }
```

Comment: You will need to add an arc.

Comment: @TaW , how do i use that for it?

Comment: See my answer for an example. I have cleaned up your code a little as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

[image]

```
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.FillMode = FillMode.Winding;

        int cut = 80;
        Rectangle cr = panel1.ClientRectangle;

        Point[] points =
        {
            new Point(0, cr.Height - cut),
            new Point(0, 0),
            new Point(cr.Width, 0),
            new Point(cr.Width, cr.Height - cut),
            new Point(cr.Width - cut, cr.Height),
            new Point(cut, cr.Height),
            new Point(0, cr.Height - cut),
        };
        path.AddPolygon(points);

        Rectangle arcRect = new Rectangle(0, cr.Height - 2 * cut, 2 * cut, 2 * cut);
        path.AddArc(arcRect, 90f, 90f);
```

An arc is defined by the bounding rectangle, which in our case has twice the size of the cut. It starts at 90° clockwise from the x-axis and goes for (at least) 90° more.

You can [add it to a GraphicsPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.addarc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [draw it with a Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142028%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object.

Here is a quote from MSDN:

> If there are previous lines or curves in the figure, a line is added
>   to connect the endpoint of the previous segment to the beginning of
>   the arc.
>
> The arc is traced along the perimeter of the ellipse bounded by the
>   specified rectangle. The starting point of the arc is determined by
>   measuring clockwise from the x-axis of the ellipse (at the 0-degree
>   angle) by the number of degrees in the start angle. The endpoint is
>   similarly located by measuring clockwise from the starting point by
>   the number of degrees in the sweep angle. If the sweep angle is
>   greater than 360 degrees or less than -360 degrees, the arc is swept
>   by exactly 360 degrees or -360 degrees, respectively.

Mote that I have added the bounding rectangle of the arc for demonstration only. The code does not include it.

For rounded cuts at other corners you nee to chang&expand the points array and add more/other arcs.

The other corners arcs take these Rectangles:

```
 Rectangle arcRectTL = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2 * cut, 2 * cut);
 Rectangle arcRectTR = new Rectangle(cr.Width - 2 * cut, 0, 2 * cut, 2 * cut);
 Rectangle arcRectBR = new Rectangle(cr.Width - 2*cut, cr.Height - 2*cut, 2*cut, 2*cut);
```

The starting angles are respectively: `180°,  270°  and 0°`.

The sizes and the sweeping angle stay the same.

Comment: can this code also work if i need to have a curve at the top left and button right and the other edges will be normal.

Comment: I have added the bounding rectangle to the image to show the logic. For other corners you have to adapt the __location and the starting angle__. The size and the sweeping angle stay the same.

Comment: could you give another example of what you mean?